# Laravel 5.2 Many to Many withPivot save

Tags: laravel

I'm having problem on this many to many. My code is

```
$purchase_order = PurchaseOrder::find(1);
$item = Item::find(1);
$purchase_order->items()->save($item);
```

This one works well. I have a pivot table name items_purchase_order it creates
item_id 1 and purchase_order_id 1

The problem is the pivotColumn on how to add it.

```
$array = [
  'qty' => 4,
  'unit_price' => '23'
];
```

My PurchaseOrder Model

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'items_purchase_orders', 'purchase_order_id', 'item_id')->withPivot('qty','unit_price');
```

I have tried other examples on here but to no avail. Like this one

```
$purchase_order = PurchaseOrder::find(1);
$item = new Item($array);
$purchase_order->items()->save($item);
```

This becomes ambiguous because there is no item id.  The items are already created and the purchase order is the one I'm going to create. I have tried the reverse one with the Item Model.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\PurchaseOrder', 'items_purchase_orders', 'item_id', 'purchase_order_id')->withPivot('qty','unit_price');

 //pivot table added with purchase_order columns
 $array = [
  'po_number' => '454jk', // I minimized it to one column. Purchase Orders Column
  'qty' => 4, // Pivot Column
  'unit_price' => '23' // Pivot Column
];

$item = Item::find(1);
$purchase_order= new PurchaseOrder($array);
$item->purchaseOrder()->save($purchase_order);
```

Still it doesn't work.

I think I found this 1
$shop->products()->attach(1, ['products_amount' => 100, 'price' => 49.99]); Yeah it work! Reference http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: if you found your own answer, you can add it as a answer if you think it benefits the wider community.